# pytest doesn't allow quotes in options

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to call pytest in Python code using the following code. The code works fine.

```
args = ['test_folder_name', '--junitxml=output.xml', '--ignore=file_to_ignore.py']
ret_code = pytest.main(args)
```

However, it throws errors if I add double quotes around the file paths in the options:

```
args = ['test_folder_name', '--junitxml="output.xml"', '--ignore="file_to_ignore.py"']
ret_code = pytest.main(args)
```

When I call pytest in command line I am able to specify the option as --junitxml=”somepath” and this allows somepath to contain spaces. Why I can't do the same thing when calling pytest.main in Python code?

Comment: Which error? / Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those quotes are handled by the shell.  Since you're not calling through the shell when using `pytest.main`, you don't need them at all.

If you add them, you will literally have quotes in your input, which can cause an error.

Either of these should work:

```
args = [..., '--ignore', 'file to ignore', ...]

args = [..., '--ignore=file to ignore', ...]
```